# Laptop battery died, many desktop settings seem to have disappeared

Tags: gnome, laptop, battery, 18.04

My laptop battery died as I was logging into my laptop this morning.  I plugged it in and booted back up.  Now I notice that my icon theme has changed, and my application bar on the left is missing a ton of shortcuts that I frequently use.  My right click setting is also messed up.  All of my application notifiers are gone in the upper right corner.  This is all that I've noticed so far, but I'm sure there's more.

Before I start making changes and doing any damage to my chances to recover things, is there anything I should do or try to do to get things back to the way that they were?  I'm using vanilla Ubuntu 18.04, so GNOME.

Comment: Is everything normal if you create a new user and log in as the new user? Run `sudo adduser username` to add a new user.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be normal.  But I'm more worried about how to get all of my old settings back.